# xmodmap keybindings don't work

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, keyboard, key-mapping, xmodmap

I am trying to use Xmodmap to add some german diareses/umlauts to my keyboard, but Xmodmap is not working with them (but is with other remappings).

I am following this guide: [German Umlauts on US Keyboard in X (Ubuntu 10.04)](http://larsmichelsen.com/open-source/german-umlauts-on-us-keyboard-in-x-ubuntu-10-04/).

## Xmodmap

I have added this to my `~/.Xmodmap`:

```
keysym a = a A adiaeresis Adiaeresis
keysym o = o O odiaeresis Odiaeresis
keysym u = u U udiaeresis Udiaeresis
keysym s = s S ssharp ssharp
```

## xev

However it doesn't work. Here's the output from `xev` when I press <kbd>o</kbd>, hold down <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, press <kbd>o</kbd>, press <kbd>x</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x4e00001,
    root 0x8e, subw 0x0, time 642618, (108,138), root:(173,190),
    state 0x10, keycode 32 (keysym 0x6f, o), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (6f) "o"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (6f) "o"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4e00001,
    root 0x8e, subw 0x0, time 642644, (108,138), root:(173,190),
    state 0x10, keycode 32 (keysym 0x6f, o), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (6f) "o"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4e00001,
    root 0x8e, subw 0x0, time 643792, (108,138), root:(173,190),
    state 0x10, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4e00001,
    root 0x8e, subw 0x0, time 645365, (108,138), root:(173,190),
    state 0x90, keycode 32 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4e00001,
    root 0x8e, subw 0x0, time 645409, (108,138), root:(173,190),
    state 0x90, keycode 32 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4e00001,
    root 0x8e, subw 0x0, time 647660, (108,138), root:(173,190),
    state 0x90, keycode 53 (keysym 0xd7, multiply), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c3 97) "×"
    XmbLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c3 97) "×"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4e00001,
    root 0x8e, subw 0x0, time 647722, (108,138), root:(173,190),
    state 0x90, keycode 53 (keysym 0xd7, multiply), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c3 97) "×"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4e00001,
    root 0x8e, subw 0x0, time 650223, (108,138), root:(173,190),
    state 0x90, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

You'll note that pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is interpreted as `ISO_Level3_Shift`, and when that and <kbd>x</kbd> is pressed, I get `keysym 0xd7, multiply`, i.e. `×`, which is set as my 3rd level for <kbd>x</kbd>. So <kbd>AltGr</kbd> works.

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep 53
keycode  53 = x X x X multiply approximate
```

However when I press <kbd>o</kbd> I get `keysym 0x0, NoSymbol`, despite my 3rd level set up:

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep 32
keycode  32 = o O odiaeresis Odiaeresis
```

Same thing happens when I try to use <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + (<kbd>a</kbd>|<kbd>u</kbd>|<kbd>s</kbd>).

## Xmodmap works for other remappings

Since my <kbd>PgUp</kbd> key on my laptop is small, I have remapped the num pad <kbd>+</kbd> to by Page Up in my `~/.Xmodmap`, and that works fine. So my XModmap file is being (partially) read.

Why does my reassigments to o/a/u not work?

I am using Ubuntu 14.0.1 trusty with Ubuntu Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preliminary note: it appears that `xmodmap` has recently changed; old settings won't work.

For your case, look at the number of values for keycode 53 (6 values: `x X x X multiply approximate`), which works, and for keycode 32 (4 values: `o O odiaeresis Odiaeresis`), which doesn't work.

`ISO_Level3_Shift` will select the 5th or 6th value, but they are not set for keycode 32 in your case. Hence the `keysym 0x0, NoSymbol` result.

What you need is:

```
keysym a = a A a A adiaeresis Adiaeresis
keysym o = o O o O odiaeresis Odiaeresis
keysym u = u U u U udiaeresis Udiaeresis
keysym s = s S s S ssharp ssharp
```

But it may better to use XKB directly ([example](https://www.vinc17.net/unix/xkb.html)).

**EDIT:** The 3rd and 4th values are selected by the `Mode_switch` key. And for each pair of values, `Shift` selects the second value of the pair. See the [ArchWiki xmodmap page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xmodmap).

Comment: That was it exactly! By adding the extra letters, I can now type the characters. :)

Comment: How can one know which modifier key uses which index in the list of values?

Comment: @topher217 I've just added the following: The 3rd and 4th values are selected by the `Mode_switch` key. And for each pair of values, `Shift` selects the second value of the pair. See the [ArchWiki xmodmap page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xmodmap).

Answer (score 0):

To make the right `Alt` key work as `Alt Gr`, it needs to be mapped to `Mode_switch` instead of `ISO_Level3_Shift`, by adding the line

```
keycode 108 = Mode_switch
```

to `~/.Xmodmap`:

```
keycode 108 = Mode_switch
keycode  38 = a A adiaeresis Adiaeresis
keycode  30 = u U udiaeresis Udiaeresis
keycode  32 = o O odiaeresis Odiaeresis
keycode  39 = s S ssharp
```

If you want the umlauts on the keys they have on the German keyboard, use:

```
keycode 108 = Mode_switch
keycode 48 = apostrophe quotedbl adiaeresis Adiaeresis
keycode 47 = semicolon colon odiaeresis Odiaeresis
keycode 34 = bracketleft braceleft udiaeresis Udiaeresis
keycode 20 = minus underscore ssharp
```

(You could combine them, of course.)